# Куда пропал терминал?

Tags: ubuntu

Нажимаю Ctrl+Alt+T, терминал не появляется. Как можно исправить? Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Проверить комбинации клавиш клавиатуры в настройках?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю вариант обхода (**Не через Ctrl+Alt+T**). То есть установить другой эмулятор терминала.

Для начала нужно перейти в консольный режим

```
Ctrl + Alt + F1
```

Далее ввести логин и пароль. После авторизации ввести:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xterm
```

Далее завершить сеанс

```
exit
```

Чтобы вернуться в графический режим нажать

```
Alt + F7
```

Потом вывести ярлык терминала в любое удобное место.

Comment: Сорри за ложный вызов... Перезагрузка компа решила проблему :D